# Deactivate DCS contol character

Tags: terminal, rsync, escape-characters, special-characters, stty

Esoteric characters in filenames sometimes lead to weird errors. I recently backed up files with `rsync`, noticing that some minutes into the process, all status output stopped. Investigating further, I found that the cause was a file name with Asian characters in it. One of the symbols had unicode value `0x0090` which I suppose my shell interpreted as [the control character `DCS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C1_set). As no corresponding `ST` character (value `0x009C`) ever followed, this caused all output to halt. After `rsync` finished, all text issued thereafter spilled out to the terminal at once.

I already consulted the `stty` manual page, but could not find a way temporarily rid this special symbol of its function for the duration of the `rsync` execution. Is there any way to deactivate these characters?

Comment: "One of the symbols had unicode value 0x0090" -- Does the filename contain the U+0090 Unicode codepoint, which has nothing to do with Asian characters? If so, in which encoding? Or does the Asian character contain (in UTF-8 I guess) the 0x90 byte? An Asian character containing another Unicode value does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally rsync should only print printable characters.

If it's not the case, you could pipe rsync's output through a filter utility such as `cat -v`, although it introduces some delay due to buffering. Also I'm not sure `cat -v` is clever enough to catch UTF-8 encoded C1, or the 0x90 byte (it's not clear to me which one you encounter).